# Getting error when running Jest tests with sfdx project at version 48

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

> When running the Jest test I'm getting this **error: Invalid sourceApiVersion
>   found in sfdx-project.json. Expected 47.0, found 48.0 error**

My sfdx-project.json looks like this

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "48.0"
}
```

HTML for component under test

```
<template>
    <div class="message">Hello World!</div>
</template>
```

Js for component under test

```
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

    export default class Modal extends LightningElement {}
```

Simplified Jest test

```
import { createElement } from "lwc";

import Modal from "c/modal";


describe("c-test-jest initialize", () => {
    it("message should be initialization", () => {
        // Setup
        const modal = initElement();


        // Exercise
        return Promise.resolve().then(() => {


            // Verify
            expect(modal.shadowRoot.querySelector(".message")).not.toBeNull();
        });
    });

    // HELPER

    function initElement() {
        let element = createElement("c-modal", {
            is: Modal
        });

        document.body.appendChild(element);
        return element;
    }
});
```

Adding Package JSON Screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update your `sfdx-lwc-jest` node dependency to a more recent version:

1. Edit `package.json`
2. Update the version of `sfdx-lwc-jest` under `devDependencies` with the proper version of 'sfdx-lwc-jest' according to your current Salesforce version from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest) in versions tab
3. Run `npm install` or `yarn install` depending on your Node package manager.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the delayed response, That was the first thing I checked. I even tried deleting node_modules folder and ran npm install but still getting the same error. I have added a screenshot for your reference.

Comment: looks like it was a cache issue, I cleared cache using npm cache clean --force and now it works

Comment: By the way you might get this error since your project is set-up on the latest none production version of Salesforce; If you do want to use the latest Salesforce version with your Jest tests, you can install the prerelease version:  npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest@prerelease --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

If you are running into this error in the Trailhead module:

[Salesforce trailhead LWC Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/test-lightning-web-components/set-up-jest-testing-framework?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components&trailmix_creator_id=tzarrjr&trailmix_slug=getting-ready-for-lb-2-b-new-to-lwc)

Running  `npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest@prerelease --save-dev` in the VS code terminal worked for me. I believe there is a lag time between when Salesforce releases their versions and when the project.json file gets updated for npm. Updating to the prelease version should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an “Invalid sourceApiVersion” error, it is due to an VS Code extension updated with the latest version of Salesforce.
"error Invalid sourceApiVersion found in sfdx-project.json. Expected 49.0, found 50.0"

In Visual Studio Code, in the top level directory, open sfdx-project.json.
Update the line of code with "sourceApiVersion" to the expected version of the error message you received.
"sourceApiVersion": "49.0"
Save the file.